# Django admin pages: Can queryset extra fields be used for sorting specific columns

Tags: django, sql-order-by, admin, django-queryset, extra

So, the extra field in a queryset can be used to add additional columns to your select query, which in turn can be set as the default ordering. I have so far been able to achieve this: created an extra field and then set it as default ordering.

```
qs = qs.extra(select={'natname':"concat('0', nat, name)"}, order_by=['natname'])
```

Now, in my admin interface, I have my other fields `{name, nat, location, space, ....}` and the results from the table are ordered by `natname` when the page is loaded...perfect.

But now I wish to enable ordering on the `name` field, but instead of ordering by `name`, I want it to order it by `natname`. Is this possible?

So even though `natname` is an extra field, I want to somehow bind the column `name` with `natname` when it comes to ordering.

Right now, if I do `qs.query.__str__()`, I get the sql query with `order by natname`. When I click on the column `name`, order by changes to `name`, but just for this special case, I wish it to order it by `natname`. Is this possible?

I have looked at how Django generates the headers and the views for these automated admin pages under `<django-installation-path>/contrib/admin` but it only references the `list_display` set defined in the `ModelAdmin` for this model. If I make any changes there, the columns displayed get changed in the admin-view.

It might sound a bit confusing. If you require particular details, please feel free to ask.

Thanks.

Comment: I've subclassed `ChangeList` to override the `get_ordering` method, pulling from a `FIELD_MAP` dictionary to convert one field's ordering to another, but it only owrks in one direction. The trouble I'm having now is getting `django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_list.result_headers` to render the opposite direction (`desc / asc`) link. `result_headers` checks `cl.order_field` which has now been overridden to `natname` and thus never finds a matching field to reverse ordering for. Boo. Let me know if you reach a solution ; )

Comment: @Shuvo: take a look at my revised, working answer below.

Comment: @Yuji: I'm doing something similar right now. I'll give mkelly33's script a shot. Thanks u guys! Tonnes of help. Appreciate.

Comment: @Shuvo yes, mkelley33's updated answer is the win button. Functionally equivalent to any other potential solution and certainly easier.

Comment: @Yuji: Absolutely...only if `natname` could be displayed. But they want `name` displayed instead and want it to be ordered by only referencing `natname`. Check below.

Comment: @Shuvo: Change `return obj.natname` to `return obj.name` and I believe you will find what you're looking for: `name` displayed and ordered by `natname`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! this is possible (at least in Django 1.2.3):

In your admin.ModelAdmin subclass:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import ClassA

class ModelAdminA(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('natname',)

    def natname(self, obj):
        return obj.name
    natname.admin_order_field = 'natname'
    natname.short_description = 'name'

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(ModelAdminA, self).queryset(request)
        qs = qs.extra(select={ 'natname': "concat('0', nat, name)" })
        return qs

admin.site.register(ClassA, ModelAdminA)
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because `ChangeList.get_ordering` first looks for a valid model field. It only searches the `ModelAdmin` and `admin_order_field` if field lookup fails (which it won't in this case)

Comment: @Yuji: thx for the insight! I'll mark this post for deletion once I give it a try. I looked at the source, and my instinct is that you're right. Boo indeed :(

Comment: @Yuji: I changed my answer. We can haz answer! See above. Thx again.

Comment: @mkelley33, nice one! I  like it. Functionally the same as mapping fields. What the heck was I doing digging into ChangeList...

Comment: @Yuji: LOL apparently you were protecting me and others from spreading/consuming misinformation. I'm glad I was able to correct myself! Thx for digging :)

Comment: @Yuju, @mkelley33: forgot to mention one little detail. the `natname` is strictly going to be used for ordering. So it cannot be displayed, which means it can't be in `list_display`. `name` is that needs to be displayed. In the solution above, `natname.admin_order_field = 'natname'` needs to be ideally `name.admin_order_field = 'natname'`...if that was possible.

Comment: @Yuju, @mkelley33: (contd.) But `ChangeList` doesn't recognize that because it sniffs up `name` as an actual db field and uses that for ordering instead of `natname`. If the check for `name` as a model attribute failed, then it would have checked its `admin_order_field`, which would have referenced `natname`, which would have been perfect.

Comment: @Shuvo, we understand that. If you take mkelley33's example verbatim, you will see it does exactly what you've asked for.

Comment: If you add `natname` to your `list_display`, there is no model field called `natname`, so it will fall back to an attribute lookup on your  `ModelAdmin`. It will then check for an `admin_order_field` which will be `natname`. `short_description` will ensure the column is named `name` and will be indistinguishable from the original `name` column you had set up previously. Do not include `name` in your `list_display`, as `natname` is now posing as your `name`.

Comment: @Shuvo, @Yuji: there may be a little confusion regarding the state of the current answer. I'm guessing that Shuvo's comment concerns the answer I had given *before* the recent edit to my answer in the natname method's implementation. @Shuvo: if you look closely, and try my answer again, you will have a working solution. Cheers!

Comment: @mkelley33: yeah its definitely a working solution. Cheers to that!

Comment: Congrats Shuvo! I will definitely be using this as well. PS: push the little up arrow :P

Comment: @Shuvo, @Yuji: I've often wanted to learn more about the django admin so I just now created a place where I can try things out: https://bitbucket.org/mkelley33/django-admin-playaround

Comment: I couldn't up the arrow, it won't let me. Its asking me to have at least 15 reputation

Comment: @Shuvo: no worries :) I'm not remotely concerned about points, votes, and badges. The learning and community here are what means the most to me!